# Donation recorded under the wrong contact name

Tags: civicontribute

Help!

When one of our donors contributed on our online contribution page with Civi, it was recorded in civi under another (unrelated) donors name. But it was recorded properly in our payment processor. Civi even sent a confirmation email to the correct email address but using the incorrect name of our donor. What went wrong?

I want to move the donation from the wrong client to the correct one, but if I try to delete the donation it says it will delete any financial record of that donation as well. Is this true? Will it delete the payment as recorded in our payment processor Authorize.net?

Thank you all.

Comment: How are you trying to move?

Comment: One way the above would be possible is if your Dedupe Rules are misconfigured

Comment: @petednz-fuzion -- good call. Thank you. Do you know where I can find info that explains how dedupe rules function?

Comment: @PradeepNayak I was planning on deleting the contribution from the incorrect donor's contribution page and then adding the donation to the correct donors page. I am worried that will delete the payment in our payment processor because a pop up warns me of that.

Comment: Go to documentation (under Support in your civi menu) and search for 'dedupe'.https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a matter of updating one contribution than you can

1. use api explorer(CiviCRM >> Support >> Developer >> API explorer 3) to update the contact id for the contribution, see below image(use the contribution id to move the contribution)

[image]
2. Execute below sql statement in your mysql (below sql statement update contribution with 23 to set contact to id 103)

sql:

```
UPDATE civicrm_contribution SET contact_id = 103 WHERE id = 23;
```

3. You can use [Move contribution](https://civicrm.org/extensions/move-contribution) extension to move contribution to different contact

Comment: Thank you!! worked like a charm.

Comment: So can you mark this as answered so that it helps someone?

Comment: yes -- but I still need to figure out why it was recorded like that in the first place... I've tried adjusting our dedupe rules, but will find out if it happens again I guess.